# Google sheets Formula highlights above match not on it

Tags: google-sheets

As the title mentions I have a small search formula just to check if the column contains a keyword that I select from another column

but when it finds the column it just highlights the row above it.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rR5iqhzjR_CM8Pys0Ur3383cRDkI-U7Z61jGRIQZoPA/edit?usp=sharing

[image: Screenshot of the sheet]

Match the keyword "World" In column E under the current ones and you'll see its highlighting above it not on it sometimes It highlights below when I change range

Formula `=SEARCH($G$2,$E3)`
Why is this happening?

Comment: When you use `E3` in your formula, you are always searching the value in the E3 cell, not the entire column. You should use `E:E` instead, as suggested in the below answers. Read the documentation of the [SEARCH function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154).

Comment: Wish I could award you with something @ManSamVampire Thank you for explaining

Comment: You can upvote my comment by clicking the  button to the left of my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is with the Conditional Formatting,

You have to apply for all cells in the range. Try something like this,

[image]

Also, use `FIND` for case-sensitive results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your search to be case sensitive you should use
EXACT() formula in Conditional Formatting

```
=EXACT($G$2,$E:E)
```